# My int function that removes the first digit of a number didn't return the number I expected

Tags: c++, recursion, numbers, function-definition

```
int removeF(int n){
       static int temp,count=0;
            if(n%10==n){
        return temp;
    }
    count++;
    temp+=(n%10)*pow(10,count-1);
    return removeF(n/10);
}
```

This is a function that removes the first digit of a number.
Everything works however the result is a little weird.
For example when I enter 123456 as my number n, it returns me 23454, which is 2 less than the result I expected.
Anyone have any idea on this problem?

Comment: @cigien temp is `static` therefore initialized with 0.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/dMdxvr). Seems to work for me.

Comment: @Eugene yes, you're absolutely right. That was silly of me. I deleted the comment, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is caused by truncation converting from floating-point to integer. `pow(10,count-1)` is not exact, so `(n%10)*pow(10,count-1)` can become 1 less than the exact value would be.

A way to fix it is by inserting `round()`:

```
temp+=(n%10)*round( pow(10,count-1) );
```

However, even after that fix, your function has a big flaw (caused by using a `static` variable): it will only work correctly when called the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Digit manipulation shouldn’t involve floating-point math unless there’s absolutely no other way to do it. Just keep track of where you are with an integer variable:

```
int temp = n;
int mult = 1;
while (temp >= 10) {
    temp /= 10;
    mult *= 10;
}
return n - mult * temp;
```

Not tested.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is too complicated. Usually it is a reason of bugs in such functions.

For starters it is a bad idea to use a static variable because it will keep its value in the next call of the function for a new number.

The function `pow` deals with float numbers. So it can be a reason of an imprecise integer computation.

The function can be written simpler.

Here you are.

```
int removeF(int n)
{
    const int Base = 10;
    
    return n % Base == n ? 0 : Base * removeF( n / Base ) + n % Base;
}
```

If to pass the number `123456` then the function will return the number `23456`.

Answer (score 0):

If the input and output of your function is an integer, you should avoid converting to a float when possible.  Floating point conversion introduces a rounding error in most cases.  Here's an example of an float-free solution:

```cpp
int removeLeadingDigit(int input)
{
    int modval = 1;
    while (input >= 10 * modval)
    {
        modval *= 10;
    }

    return input % modval;
}
```

There are some other problems with your code, too, such as the use of static variables.  Only use `static` in function variables for things that need to be preserved between calls.